# Need for range in a for loop

Tags: python, for-loop

```
def sum_items(list1, list2):
    sum_list = []
    for i in range(len(list1)):
        sum_list.append(list1[i] + list2[i])


return sum_list
```

Why is the range function needed for something like this? Would the result not be the same if we simply used the len of list1?

Comment: `for i in 15` doesn't really make sense when you look at it. Python needs something to *iterate* over, it can't do that with a single number.

Comment: In my opinion and experience, in almost all cases of `for i in range(len(iterable))` you should rethink your code. Python has a lot of tools which make explicit iterating over indices unnecessary: zipping, enumerating, mapping, reducing (not anymore), etc

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because a `for` loop in Python is really a [for each loop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreach_loop); you need to give it an *iterable* to loop over; you are not looping for a certain number of iterations, you are iterating over elements, one element after another.

If you were to try to loop over just the length, you'd get an exception:

```
>>> for i in 42:
...     pass
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

For your **specific** example, you don't need to use `range()` either, I'd use the [`zip()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) instead:

```
def sum_items(list1, list2):
    sum_list = []
    for i, j in zip(list1, list2)
        sum_list.append(i + j)
    return sum_list
```

or, combined with a list comprehension:

```
def sum_items(list1, list2):
    return [i + j for i, j in zip(list1, list2)]
```

or using [`sum()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) to just sum *all* values in each zipped tuple:

```
def sum_items(list1, list2):
    return [sum(t) for t in zip(list1, list2)]
```

`zip()` takes elements from each of the argument iterables and pairs up the elements, one by one; `[1, 2, 3]` and `['foo', 'bar', 'baz']` becomes `[(1, 'foo'), (2, 'bar'), (3, 'baz')]`. More input arguments mean more elements in the output tuples.

Answer (score 0):

Using just the len(list1) for your iterator only gives one value - the length of the list.  If you want to iterate over the whole set of values in each list, you need to create a range of all the indexes - using the range() operator.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you don't need neither `range` nor a `for`-loop. Your problem is a simple list comprehension:

```
[sum(t) for t in zip(list1,list2)]
```

In my personal experience and opinion, in most cases when you see `range(len(x))`, something is wrong with the design.